# How to generate coverage from setup.py

Tags: python, code-coverage

I have a setup.py that runs tests via the common `test_suite: "tests"` setting.  What is the best way to generate coverage from here?  I figured that by running setup.py via the coverage tool, it would include setup.py in its coverage reports?

I have a load_tests hook in my tests/**init**.py, which I thought would be a nice place to enable coverage, but even that is too early, since it would start coverage before tests.  Then there is the setUpClass function, but that would involve modifying every single test to include another module to start and stop coverage from here.  It all seems rather clunky.

Comment: Erm, whats wrong with `python coverage.py setup.py`?

Comment: Won't that generate coverage for setup.py and the setuptools modules?

Comment: Nope, it _should_ generate the results for all the files it uses, have you tried it so far?

Comment: It generated coverage for everything.  i.e. httplib and such.

Comment: Maybe being able to setup inclusion/exclusions like with Bullseye would help.

Comment: is that not what you wanted?

Comment: No, I wanted to generate a coverage report for just the modules I have written, not what they include.  Don't see the point of reporting coverage on third party modules.

Comment: Okay, if I do that and apply a filter at report generation time instead of run-time, then that seems to be good enough.

Answer (score 11):

This will report coverage just for the module you want, assuming that you have a Python module "my_module" with all your `.py` files and other modules in it:

```
coverage run --source=my_module/ setup.py test
```

Answer (score 4):

Just need to apply the filter at report generation time instead of at run-time like Bullseye does:

```
coverage run ./setup.py test
coverage html --include=libgsync/\*
```